# Which IBM Bluemix service allows you to convert data into an SQL database?

Tags: db2, informix, ibm-cloud, dashdb

Which IBM Bluemix service allows you to convert data into an SQL database?
IBM DB2, object storage, MongoDB by compos, or Apache Spark Boiler Plate?

Comment: To add on here, mongodb and object storage are in no way SQL data storage technologies. There's a huge difference there. You should take the time to read up on those deltas before investing time in one.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean "store" in a SQL database, then there are a couple options. The "sqldb" service is based on DB2 and is for the regular (traditional) relational processing of data. The "dashDB" service is for analytic processing of relational data and is also based on DB2 and uses the BLU Acceleration technology. There are also services offered that feature the full DB2 functionality or make use of the Informix TimeSeries feature.

The "sqldb" and "dashDB" services can be interfaced via input and output nodes in the Node-RED starter kit. All services have suitable drivers for the offered runtimes (node.js, Python, Java, ...).